# How Parsing Data List Item Dropdown in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i have code dropdown menu, but i will parsing list item 
to make a dropdown menu template so I just change the list item section.

```
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: <String>['Instagram', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

Comment: Can you share example list? Also, please explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
class DropDownTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropDownTestState createState() => _DropDownTestState();
}

class _DropDownTestState extends State<DropDownTest> {
  MenuItem dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<MenuItem>(
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        value: dropdownValue,
        onChanged: (MenuItem newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>>((MenuItem value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value.name),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}

class MenuItem {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  const MenuItem(this.id, this.name);
}

const List<MenuItem> items = [
  MenuItem(1, 'ONE'),
  MenuItem(2, 'TWO'),
  MenuItem(3, 'THREE'),
  MenuItem(4, 'FOUR'),
];
```

Comment: sorri dude, how if i have 2 Items list?

Comment: @BadaiArdiat You can merge them, but if you have different list of different objects, create another question because it's very different thing from this topic. It's about Abstraction.

Comment: ok sir, i create new topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899410/how-parsing-data-dropdown-with-2-different-list-of-different-objects-in-flutter

Comment: @BadaiArdiat I mean, if your Object Types are same you don't need to create another question, but if they are different type of objects and if you want to merge them inside one DropDown, yes create the question.