# How Parsing Data Dropdown With 2 different list of different objects in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How i can build dropdown with 1 template Dropdown with 2 different List Item.
iam very confused.
i have 1 class Dropdown but i want  2 different  List just using 1 class Dropdown
I hope you understand what I mean

```
DropdownButton<MenuItem>(
            isExpanded: true,
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (MenuItem newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>>((MenuItem value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value.name),
              );
            }).toList());
      }

    class MenuItem {
      final int id;
      final String name;

      const MenuItem(this.id, this.name);
    }
    const List<MenuItem> items = [
      MenuItem(1, 'Facebook'),
      MenuItem(2, 'Instagram'),
      MenuItem(3, 'THREE'),
      MenuItem(4, 'FOUR'),
    ];
```

[image]

Comment: and i have different List
const List<MenuItem> items = [
  MenuItem(1, 'TV'),
  MenuItem(2, 'Radio'),
  MenuItem(3, 'Internet'),
  MenuItem(4, 'Website'),
];

Comment: Please try to explain more.

Comment: i have 1 class Dropdown but i want  2 different  List just using 1 class Dropdown

Comment: Is that 2 different Lists contains different objects types or same object type? I mean those lists containts only `MenuItem` objects or there is a  like `MenuItem2` object?

Comment: I have `MenuItem1` and `MenuItem2` with different Object just using 1 class dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is, merging different objects via abstraction. Now we have `MenuItem` abstract class and we use it inside the widget clas, because we need a common `Class` to merge different objects. Since they have common `String` field to show inside the `DropdownMenu`, it's easy to how to merge. No problem there.

Also this means:

```
[...items1, ...items2]
```

We are creating a new list combined by two other lists.

This question is more about `OOP` rather than `Flutter`. Try to make some practise for `Abstraction` you'll figure out.

Our `DropdownMenu` value variable under the `State` class:

```
class _DropDownTestState extends State<DropDownTest> {
  MenuItem value;
```

And the solution, this is the DropDown widget:

```
DropdownButton<MenuItem>(
    isExpanded: true,
    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
    value: value,
    onChanged: (MenuItem newValue) {
      setState(() {
        value = newValue;
      });
    },
    items: <MenuItem>[...items1, ...items2]
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>>((MenuItem value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value.name),
      );
    }).toList())
```

These are the Class of different objects connected with one abstract class:

```
abstract class MenuItem {
  final String name;

  const MenuItem(this.name);
}

class MenuItem1 extends MenuItem {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  const MenuItem1(this.id, this.name) : super(name);
}

class MenuItem2 extends MenuItem {
  final String name;
  final double price;

  const MenuItem2(this.price, this.name) : super(name);
}
```

Lists:

```
const List<MenuItem1> items1 = [
  MenuItem1(1, 'ONE'),
  MenuItem1(2, 'TWO'),
  MenuItem1(3, 'THREE'),
];

const List<MenuItem2> items2 = [
  MenuItem2(10, 'FOO'),
  MenuItem2(50, 'BAR'),
  MenuItem2(90, 'BAZ'),
];
```

Comment: sorry sir , i mean 2 diffrent list to different Object using 1 class dropdown

Comment: @BadaiArdiat so just merge the lists like my example up above and use it before `.map` function, `[...items1, ...items2]` this is the method.

Comment: what about callback, it will trigger 2 times or single time?

Comment: @Vikas no, callback will trigger once if you asking for merged array.